# Where is Rsync protocol documented?

Tags: rsync

The pdf here shows the algorithm of rsync: https://openresearch-repository.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/40765/3/TR-CS-96-05.pdf

I can't seem to find the RFC article or the Protocol documentation. Does anyone know where I can find that?

Where can I find the exact protocol for the rsync client and rsync server?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is an official protocol spec. E.g. see the "The Rsync Protocol" section of this page: https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html . The one time I implemented a client for it, I did so from the source code. It has not been standardized by the IETF, so no RFC.

This is likely the reason there aren't a lot of libraries implementing rsync. (That and the command itself usually suffices.) On the one hand this is unfortunate because the world would be a better place if more things had efficient incremental sync. On the flipside, I'm not sure many of the applications where it would be useful want to use the protocol so much as the algorithm inside some other protocol...

Comment: Apparently there are alternatives that are documented. E.g. https://docs.syncthing.net/specs/bep-v1.html . This likely doesn't help much if you need to interoperate with rsync however.